# how can I filter and place .java file from one folder to another folder in unix server. I am not able to write java code for this

Tags: java

i got job to transfer .java files from one folder in server to another folder. I need to write this code in java language and need to share it with server team to schedule this job

Comment: SO is not a coding service. Check tutorials on how to write a Java program and topics on listing and moving files in Java. If then, you are stuck, we well gladly help you.

Comment: ??? Sounds like a programming assignment for a class?  If not, just use `cp` or `rsync`

Answer (score 0):

Please follow below link -

**https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-move-file-to-another-directory-in-java/**

I think this will be helpful for you.